# Can you merge IP edits to a username in Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

Is it possible to merge edits from an IP to a user account in Wikipedia?

I'm guessing there might be some 'owner' issues, but if one could prove no-one else used the IP apart from 'guest' posts and logged in user posts, could the edits be merged to a named user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Username (and also IP) merging is technically possible but isn't done. It would require a highly manual effort by database admins. And yes it is hard to proof that this were your edits (how should they know if it was you?).

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. It just looks a bit suss when you have orphan edits on a work IP when you forgot to log in <_<

Comment: Well it should just happen automatically if you notice and login with the same IP. (Within some time period due to shared or dynamic IPs.)

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible for bureaucrats to merge user accounts in MediaWiki wikis, without manually editing the database, using the [User Merge and Delete feature](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUser_Merge_and_Delete). However, this extension [is disabled on the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia%3aUsername_policy&oldid=549253300#Deleting_and_merging_accounts). It is enabled on Wikivoyage for purposes of migrating user accounts from the old Wikivoyage/Wikitravel. There is a (partial) list of [wikis that have the feature enabled](http://wikiapiary.com/wiki/Extension%3aUser_Merge_and_Delete).

I'm not sure whether the tool lets you merge anonymous (IP) accounts. I didn't see any such merges in the logs of a few wikis from the list, but that doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: No, it is not possible to merge edits from IPs and user accounts together. There are actually two different things inside the MediaWiki database